# Create read stream (utf-8) without breaking words

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read a large file and trying find the number of occurrence of some certain words. So I'm creating a read stream (`fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'utf-8' })`) and as I receive a chunk, I pass it to a worker to do the splitting and searching (`stream.on('data' passToWorker)`).

I noticed that it actually is not giving the correct count, which I think is because of the chunk I receive from the stream has broken words.

A possible solution to this would using `realine` to get line by line, but that takes forever. I'm wondering if we can find a solution without having to compromise the speed.

Thanks

Comment: It all depends on your worker implementation. You should implement it in such a way that it will take chunks into account.

Comment: So here is how I implemented it. My main thread does the streaming and as the chunk comes, it sends it to the worker and as the next chunk comes it is sent to a different worker. May be you wanted suggest a solution where we keep track of the first and last part of the chunk to check if there is a broken word.